# UI5 controller in ES Module (.mjs) format

Tags: sapui5, es6-modules

Is it possible to write UI5 controllers in ES Module (`.mjs`) format to get a strict mode and other ES Modules features enabled by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the ES Modules support in UI5 controllers, as of the 2020.Q4, the [response](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3042#issuecomment-708341725) of the SAP UI5 team as follows:

> *The `ui5loader` supports only AMD or native global scripts, but no ES6 modules. A two-way, seamless integration of ES6 modules and AMD (without transpiling) is tricky, as ES6 has a different dependency resolution model than AMD (the most tricky part is to make AMD's asynchronous dependency resolution transparent for ES6 code). We experimented a while with such a mixture, but don't see a satisfying solution.*

Regarding the strict mode itself in UI5, [according](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3055#issuecomment-716638879) to the SAP UI5-team, in OpenUI5, strict mode is ensured by the active ESLint rules, and therefore, can be used everywhere, while in case of SAPUI5 not all code uses strict mode. Hence, it is better to apply "use strict"; in function scope only, to avoid the potentially possible problems.